# How to select a specific item in django database

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

How do I translate the following to a Django database search?

```
SELECT column1 FROM TABLE 'my_table' WHERE column2 = 'some text'
```

So far I've tried this, which is the wrong syntax:

```
my_table.objects.get(column1,column2 = 'some text')
```

Comment: [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the model instance by `column2` using [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) and retrieve the value of `column1` field:

```
my_table.objects.get(column2='some text').column1
```

Note that if the object would not be found, `get()` throws [`DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.DoesNotExist) exception which you probably want to handle separately. Also, if there would be more than one object found, it would throw [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned) exception, which is also something you need to think about beforehand.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) with [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values):

```
my_table.objects.filter(column2='some text').values('column1')
```

This would return a `ValuesQuerySet` (think about it as a list of dictionaries).

Comment: Note that it also raises a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error if multiple rows match the query. In most cases this is trivial, but in this case `column2` might not have a unique constraint and return multiple values.

Comment: @knbk that's a good point, I'll add a note about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways out , here is one :

```
obj = my_table.objects.get(column2="any_item").column1
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but that will return a whole row where column2='anyitem' whereas i want a specific item in that row, specifically the contents of column1